# How to find solution to equation A + modinv(A,n) mod n == -1

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, inverse, roots-of-unity

given an odd prime n, is there an simple or elegant way to solve an equation

**A + modinv(A,n) mod n == -1**

whereby modinv(A,n) is the modular multiplicative inverse of A modulo n (i.e. A * modinv(A,n) mod n == 1).

Stated in other terms, the equation sums up A with its modinv in order to yield n-1. The fact that the equation mixes A with its inverse poses a difficulty I am unable to surpass.

How can I identify such As?

Thank You in advance for any hint in useful direction.

Comment: As long as $n$ isn't even you can use the quadratic equation to reduce this to solving $m^2\equiv -3\pmod n$

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve
$$
x + x^{-1} \equiv -1 \mod p
$$
for some odd prime p. This is equivalent to
$$
x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p
$$
where we have multiplied both sides by $x$ and moved everything to the left hand side. If you remember the quadratic formula, the solutions of the above equations are
$$
x_{1,2}=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4}}{2}=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}.
$$
The prime $p$ is odd, so $2$ is invertible and we don't have any problems with the denominator. The only problem left is computing $\sqrt{-3} \mod p$. Note that there isn't always a solution to the above equation. $-3$ can either be a square or not be one depending on $p$. To be more precise, you can deduce from [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) that $-3$ is a square mod $p$ if and only if
$$
\left(\dfrac{-3}{p}\right)=1 \text{ or } 0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
p \equiv 1,3,7 \mod 12
$$